# After login, desktop appears but there's no menu

Tags: xorg

After login, desktop appears but there's no menu
what can i do to get it back

Comment: which menu?, what version of ubuntu are you using?

Comment: It's likely somehow that the Unity plugin is not enabled in Compiz, did you make any changes recently?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Comment: Maybe you're missing a package; try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-session`